# Write a file from a Google Cloud Function to Firebase Storage using Node fs.writeFile?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, fs

I'm getting audiofiles from Google Text-to-Speech and then I want to write the files to Firebase Storage. I copied the Text-to-Speech code from [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) and the Firebase Storage code from [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/use-google-cloud-client-libraries-to-store-files-save-entities-and-log-data). Here's my Google Cloud Function:

```js
    exports.Google_T2S = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/T2S_Request').onUpdate((change, context) => { 
      if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {

        // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
        async function test() {
          try {
            const word = change.after.data().word; // the text
            const longLanguage = 'Spanish';
            const audioFormat = '.mp3';

            const fs = require('fs');
            const util = require('util');
            const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech'); // Imports the Google Cloud client library
            const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(); // Creates a client

            let myWordFile = word.replace(/ /g,"_"); // replace spaces with underscores in the file name
            myWordFile = myWordFile.toLowerCase(); // convert the file name to lower case
            myWordFile = myWordFile + audioFormat; // append .mp3 to the file name;

            // boilerplate copied from https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/use-google-cloud-client-libraries-to-store-files-save-entities-and-log-data
            const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
            const storage = new Storage();
            const bucket = storage.bucket('myProject-cd99d.appspot.com');
            const file = bucket.file('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + myWordFile);

            const request = {     // Construct the request
              input: {text: word},
              // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
              voice: {languageCode: 'es-ES', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE'},
              // Select the type of audio encoding
              audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
            };

            const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
            // Write the binary audio content to a local file
            const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
            await writeFile(file, response.audioContent, 'binary');
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
        test();
      } // close if
      return 0;
    });
```

The problem is here:

```js
    const file = bucket.file('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + myWordFile);
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    await writeFile(file, response.audioContent, 'binary');
```

[fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) expects `file` to be a `string`, `Buffer`, `URL`, or `integer`. It doesn't like that I put in a Google Cloud Storage function. What should I put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node's `fs` module is only for writing the local filesystem, so you can't use it to write to Cloud Storage.  If you want to write to Cloud Storage, you're going to have to use the [Cloud Storage SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/) (or the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start), which wraps the Cloud Storage SDK).

Comment: Thanks, I've refactored the code with bucket.upload() and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227123/set-the-location-path-to-firebase-storage-from-a-google-cloud-function