# Save an audiofile from Google Text-to-Speech to Firebase Storage using Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, google-text-to-speech

We're trying to get an audiofile from Google Text-to-Speech and save it to Firebase Storage, using a Google Cloud Function. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for Google Text-to-Speech show how to get an audiofile and save it locally:

```js
// Performs the Text-to-Speech request
const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
// Write the binary audio content to a local file
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3');
```

This results in an error message `Error: EROFS: read-only file system`. Google Cloud Storage doesn't allow writing files locally.

Using Firebase Storage `bucket.upload()` has a few problems:

```js
   const destinationPath = 'Audio/Spanish' + filename.ogg;
   // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
   const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
   // response.audioContent is the downloaded file
   await bucket.upload(response.audioContent, {
      destination: destinationPath
   ));
```

The error message is `TypeError: Path must be a string`. The first parameter of `bucket.upload()` is `The fully qualified path to the file you wish to upload to your bucket.` and is expected to be a string so `response.audioContent` doesn't work.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#upload) for `bucket.upload()` suggests that `destination: destinationPath` is where we should put the path to the Firebase Storage location. Is this correct?

How do we take the audiofile from Google Text-to-Speech (`response.audioContent`) and save it as a string that `bucket.upload()` can access? Or should we use something else instead of `bucket.upload()`?

Here's our full cloud function:

```js
exports.Google_T2S = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/T2S_Request').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {

    // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
    async function test() {
      try {
        const word = change.after.data().word; // the text
        const longLanguage = 'Spanish';
        const audioFormat = '.mp3';
        // copied from https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs
        const fs = require('fs');
        const util = require('util');
        const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech'); // Imports the Google Cloud client library
        const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(); // Creates a client

        let myWordFile = word.replace(/ /g,"_"); // replace spaces with underscores in the file name
        myWordFile = myWordFile.toLowerCase(); // convert the file name to lower case
        myWordFile = myWordFile + audioFormat; // append .mp3 to the file name;

        // copied from https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/use-google-cloud-client-libraries-to-store-files-save-entities-and-log-data
        const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
        const storage = new Storage();
        const bucket = storage.bucket('myProject-cd99d.appspot.com');
        const destinationPath = 'Audio/Spanish/' + myWordFile;

        const request = { // Construct the request
          input: {text: word},
          // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
          voice: {languageCode: 'es-ES', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE'},
          // Select the type of audio encoding
          audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
        };

        const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
        // Write the binary audio content to a local file
        const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
        await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
        console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3')
        // response.audioContent is the downloaded file

        await bucket.upload(response.audioContent, {
          destination: destinationPath
        });
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    test();
  } // close if
  return 0; // prevents an error message "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file.save()` was the answer. `util.promisify` was unnecessary, and causes an error message about `original` something. Here's the finished cloud function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

async function textToSpeechRequest() {
    try 
              {
                const word = change.after.data().word; // the text
                const longLanguage = 'Spanish';
                const audioFormat = '.mp3';
                // copied from https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs
                const util = require('util');
                const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech'); // Imports the Google Cloud client library
                const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(); // Creates a client

                let myWordFile = word.replace(/ /g,"_"); // replace spaces with underscores in the file name
                myWordFile = myWordFile.toLowerCase(); // convert the file name to lower case
                myWordFile = myWordFile + audioFormat; // append .mp3 to the file name;

                // copied from https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/use-google-cloud-client-libraries-to-store-files-save-entities-and-log-data
                const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
                const storage = new Storage();
                const bucket = storage.bucket('myProject-cd99d.appspot.com');
                var file = bucket.file('Audio/Spanish/' + myWordFile);

                const request = { // Construct the request
                  input: {text: word},
                  // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
                  voice: {languageCode: 'es-ES', ssmlGender: 'FEMALE'},
                  // Select the type of audio encoding
                  audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
                };

                const options = { // construct the file to write
                  metadata: {
                    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
                    metadata: {
                      source: 'Google Text-to-Speech'
                    }
                  }
                };

                // copied from https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs
                const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
                // Write the binary audio content to a local file
                // response.audioContent is the downloaded file
                return await file.save(response.audioContent, options)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log("File written to Firebase Storage.")
                  return;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error(error);
                });
            } // close try
            catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            } // close catch
    } // close async function declaration
  
    exports.Google_T2S = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/T2S_Request').onUpdate((change, context) => {
          if (change.after.data().word !== undefined) 
          {
            textToSpeechRequest();
          } // close if
      
      
    }); // close Google_T2S
```

We're getting an error `TypeError: [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function at Object.promisify`. This error doesn't appear to effect the cloud function.

To reiterate the stuff that didn't work, `fs.createWriteStream` didn't work because Google Cloud Functions can't handle [Node file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) commands. Instead, Google Cloud Functions have their own [methods](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File) that wrap the Node file system commands. [bucket.upload()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket#upload) will upload a local file to a bucket, but the path to the local file has to be a string, not a buffer or a stream coming from an API. [file.save()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#save) is documented as

> Write arbitrary data to a file.
>
> This is a convenience method which wraps `File#createWriteStream`.

That's what I want! If there's one thing about my data, it's arbitrary. Or maybe contrary by nature. After that we just had to straighten out the `contentType` (`audio/mpeg`, not `mp3`) and the file path.

Comment: why does `const bucket..` commented out?