# How to upload Google Cloud text to speech API's response to Cloud Storage [Node.js]

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-text-to-speech

I make a simple audio creating web app using Node.js server. I would like to create audio using Cloud text to speech API and then upload that audio to Cloud storage.

(I use Windows 10, Windows Subsystems for Linux, Debian 10.3 and Google Chrome browser. )

This is the code in Node.js server.

```
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
        async function quickStart() {

            // The text to synthesize
            const text = 'hello, world!';

            // Construct the request
            const request = {
                input: {text: text},
                // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
                voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
                // select the type of audio encoding
                audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
            };

            // Performs the text-to-speech request
            const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
            // Write the binary audio content to a local file
            console.log(response);
```

I would like to upload `response` to Cloud Storage.

Can I upload `response` to Cloud Storage directly? Or Do I have to save `response` in Node.js server and upload it to Cloud Storage?

I searched the Internet, but couldn't find the way to upload `response` to Cloud Storage directly. So, if you have a hint, please tell me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that, with all your code in the same file. The best way for you to achieve that, it's by using a Cloud Function, that will be the one sending the file to your Cloud Storage. **But, yes, you will need to save your file using Node.js, so then, you will upload it to Clou Storage.**

To achieve that, you will need to save your file locally and then, upload it to Cloud Storage. As you can check in a complete tutorial in this other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241849/save-an-audiofile-from-google-text-to-speech-to-firebase-storage-using-google-cl), you need to construct the file, save it locally and then, upload it. Below code is the main part you will need to add in your code.

```
...
const options = { // construct the file to write
     metadata: {
          contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
          metadata: {
              source: 'Google Text-to-Speech'
          }
     }
};

// copied from https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs
const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
// Write the binary audio content to a local file
// response.audioContent is the downloaded file
     return await file.save(response.audioContent, options)
     .then(() => {
         console.log("File written to Firebase Storage.")
         return;
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
     });
...
```

Once you have this part implemented, you will have the file that is saved locally downloaded and ready to be uploaded. I would recommend you to take a better look at the other post I [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245080/12767257), in case you have more doubts on how to achieve it.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail answer. Your solution worked perfecly!